# How to make compiler check string argument is valid in Typescript?

Tags: string, typescript, string-literals, compile-time, type-safety

In TypeScript, how should one go about having the compiler determine whether or not a string is a valid argument to a method/function?

Right now, I am using string literals to accomplish this. For example,

```
type ValidLetter = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D"; // string literal definition

public PostLetter(letter: ValidLetter) {
    ...
    api.post("https://example.com/letters/", letter);
    // POST method only accepts "A", "B", "C", or "D"
}

PostLetter("A") // All good!
PostLetter("Z") // Compiler error
```

The only thing is, at compile time, I don't know the values I will be passing in to the Post method. I could be receiving any kind of string,

```
let a = "A";
let foobar = "foobar";

PostLetter(a) // Compiler error
PostLetter(foobar) // Compiler error
```

What I'm looking for is a way of checking if a string is a valid member of a string literal. I've already attempted using `typeof`, `instanceof`, user-defined type guards, and casting. None of them seem to have what it takes.

How would I go about determining that `a` is a member of `ValidLetter` and `foobar` is not? Or perhaps string literals are not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a mix of value maps, as well as the user-defined type guards:

```
const ValidLetterMap = { A: 1, B: 1, C: 1, D: 1 };
type ValidLetter = keyof typeof ValidLetterMap;

declare function postLetter(letter: ValidLetter): void;

postLetter("A"); // ok
postLetter("E"); // err

const a = "A";
postLetter(a); // ok

let a$ = "A";
postLetter(a$); // err, a$ is of type string since it is mutable

function isValidLetter(letter: string): letter is ValidLetter {
    return letter in ValidLetterMap;
}

if (isValidLetter(a$)) {
    postLetter(a$); // now ok because we've "proven" that a$ is a valid letter
}
```

Edit: here's a generic form, relying on a slight hack to expose typing.

```
class StringLiteral<T extends string> {
    private literalSet: {[P in T]: true};

    // sort of a hack so we can expose a union type of valid letters
    public get typeProvider(): T {
        throw new Error("typeProvider is only meant for typing info, it has no value");
    }

    constructor(...literals: T[]) {
        this.literalSet = literals.reduce(
            (acc, curr) => (acc[curr] = true, acc),
            {} as {[P in T]: true}
        );
    }

    public isValid(candidate: string): candidate is T {
        return candidate in this.literalSet;
    }
}

// how to use
const lettersLiteral = new StringLiteral("A", "B", "C", "D");

declare function postLetter(letter: typeof lettersLiteral.typeProvider): void;

let a$ = "A";
postLetter(a$); // not ok

if (lettersLiteral.isValid(a$)) {
    postLetter(a$); // ok!!
}
```

Comment: Your `isValidLetter` function gives me a compiler error. The `return` line gives "[ts] 'ValidLetter' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Comment: Hmm, I was able to name them the same in the TS playground. I went and changed the value's name to `ValidLetterMap` to make them different.

Comment: Awesome, this works! Is there any way to abstract this behavior? It looks like I would have to declare a const, type, and validation function each time I want to do this. I would want something like:  
    `let lettersLiteral = new StringLiteral("A", "B", "C", "D");  
    let a = "A";  
    var letter: ValidLetter;  
    if (lettersLiteral.isValid(a)) {  
      letter = a;  
    }`

Comment: Added a generic form in the post above. It mostly follows from the previous example, save for the existence of `typeProvider`, a getter value that is really only meant to expose a type for the provided letters. This works, but it's not great.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript simply does not do any runtime type checking. Type checking happens at compile time, and type information isn't included in the produced JavaScript file.

***post.ts***

```
type ValidLetter = "A" | "B" | "C";

function post(letter: ValidLetter) {
}
```

Produces the following JavaScript:

***post.js***

```
function post(letter) {
}
```

So you have to re-specify the type check yourself manually in runtime code:

```js
type ValidLetter = "A" | "B" | "C";

function post(letter: ValidLetter) {
  if (letter !== "A" && letter !== "B" && letter !== "C") throw "error!";
}
```

Not too bad.  But it's a bit redundant, isn't it?

There's a library called [runtypes](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes), that allows you to specify your types once, and it produces a compile-time TypeScript type, as well as keeping type information to do runtime checks:

```js
import { Literal, Union, Static } from 'runtypes'

const ValidLetter = Union(Literal('A'), Literal('B'), Literal('C'));
type ValidLetter = Static<typeof ValidLetter>;

function post(letter: ValidLetter) {
    ValidLetter.check(letter);
}
```

So now you get both full compile-time checks, and runtime checks.